# Creating a year-quarter object in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a string

```
YearQtr = '2002-Q1'
```

Is there any way to convert above string to *pandas* date object with quarter format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use [`Period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html):

```
p = pd.Period(YearQtr, freq='Q')
print (p)
2002Q1
```

Or:

```
p = pd.Period(YearQtr)
```